# Installing vim8.2 with python3.8 : Python.h not found

Tags: vim8, python

I have cloned the vim git repository (even tried to run `git clean -xdf` prior to configuring, as suggested [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2984)), then compiled with:

```
./configure --with-python3-command=python3.8 
--with-python3-config-dir=$LOCAL_INSTALL/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu 
--with-features=huge --enable-python3interp=yes -
-prefix=$LOCAL_INSTALL
```

where the argument for `--with-python3-config-dir` has been taken from `python3.8-config --configdir`.

I have checked that I can see the following line when compiling:

```
checking if compile and link flags for Python 3 are sane... yes
```

When running `make` I get:

```
gcc -c -I. -I/home/myuser/envs/myenv/include/python3.8 -pthread -fPIE  -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_ATHENA -DFUNCPROTO=15 -DNARROWPROTO  -I/home/myuser/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1        -o objects/if_python3.o if_python3.c
if_python3.c:69:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Is it a problem concerning my python installation ? If so, how do I fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried, `--with-python3-config-dir=$LOCAL_INSTALL/lib/python3.8`. That works for me.

Comment: just tried, unfortunately I still get the same error. It is interesting that in the error message, the first python path printed doesn't have anything to do with the paths that I pass to the `configure`. It is linked to the output of `which python3.8` though

Comment: Do you actually have a `Python.h` file somewhere under your python3.8 installation directory though? How did you install that Python distribution? Which O.S. and distribution are you on? What is your motivation to install from source? Why not use the Vim from your distribution?

Comment: 1) `$LOCAL_INSTALL/include/python3.8/Python.h` 2) I've installed Python3.8 from source, that's why I was asking if maybe there was something wrong with it 3) Scientific Linux release 6.6. 4-5) The default Vim is quite old, and it isn't compatible with many plugins I use

Comment: Maybe like this: `CFLAGS="-I$LOCAL_INSTALL/include/python3.8 ./configure ...`.

Comment: Does `--with-python3-config-dir=$LOCAL_INSTALL` fix your build then?

Comment: Scientific Linux 6 is *old*!!! You should at least move on to the latest Scientific Linux 7. But long term, you should plan to move to a different distribution, since Scientific Linux has been discontinued... CentOS is a similar distribution and if you add EPEL packages you might be able to find most scientific packages you were planning to use. CentOS 8 is available with reasonably recent packages.

Comment: @Ralf that did work ! if you add an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @filbranden unfortunately this is on a university/work server so I can't really do much about the OS

Comment: Even though the answer's been accepted already, I'll add something: If you're working with virtual environments, this may also lead to problems finding the `Python.h` header. Once you `deactivate`, it should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention in the comments, that the file `Python.h` is located in the directory `$LOCAL_INSTALL/include/python3.8`. This directory is not in the search path for include files. So it has to be added manually.

```
export CFLAGS="-I$LOCAL_INSTALL/include/python3.8"
./configure ...
```

The `configure` script adds the compiler flags from the environment variable `CFLAGS` to the compiler command line when creating the `Makefile`.

Comment: I’m actually surprised this works... the commands given in the OP include this (having substituted what I take to be the LOCAL_INSTALL variable)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, surprising